# Changing img src attribute on iPad using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, safari

I have a script changing img src, it runs great on every browser except Safari on iPad. Here it is:

```
$("#carousel a").click(function() {
  var itemId = $(this).attr("itemid");
  $("#collection-photo img").attr("src", "path_"+itemId);
});
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="collection-photo">
  <img src="path_0" alt=""/>
</div>
<ul id="carousel">
  <li><a href="#" itemid="1"><img src="some_img_1" alt=""/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" itemid="2"><img src="some_img_2" alt=""/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" itemid="3"><img src="some_img_3" alt=""/></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

All the pathes are right, cause it works in every browser, as I said earlier. I use jQuery 1.9.1.

Thank you.

***Sorry for that question, guys. The problem was with bad russian CMS and I solved it, thanks for your help.***

Comment: What browser did you use in iPad? Safari?

Comment: @busy on a project: It shouldn't matter what browser; iOS only has a single renderer.

Comment: Sorry for that question, guys. The problem was in bad russian CMS and I solved it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it is always a good thing to stop the link from executing, especially when it comes to images. Clicking a # will reload some browsers unless we return false/preventDefault

```
$("#carousel a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
  var itemId = $(this).attr("itemid");
  $("#collection-photo img").attr("src", "path_"+itemId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check [iOS image size restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15)
2. Try debugging, add `alert(itemId)` to check if attributes properly reading and click actually being handled. Try `data-`attributes instead.
3. `return false` or `preventDefault` as suggested earlier.